# How to allow users select a different Initial View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I have an app that when the user launches the app for the first time, it will show an array of buttons. Once the user selects a button, it will push to a new view controller.

How can I make the app remember to go straight to the selected viewcontroller the next time the user launches the app?

Comment: Just use NSUserDefaults to save the choice of user.

Comment: @GeorgeAsda I feel like its easier said than done. Do you know how I write that?

Comment: Google it. There are million of tutorials out there. Don't expect anyone to write the code for you.

Comment: you need to make an effort and try something... `NSUserDefaults` is a good starting point, also add more tags in your question  do you use Swift ? Objective-c ? xib ? storyboard ?

Comment: @Aladin I am using storyboard with objective c

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out, you should use `NSUserDefaults` to save your user choice on the first session. And then on the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` (check ) of your main controller you can push the saved one.

Comment: Note that `viewDidLoad` will not be called on your main controller when app come back from background, and it's great because in this case your users is probably already displaying the sub controller that he want.

Answer (score 0):

here is some code of how to set the initial controller..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LogInVC"];//change this identifier to get a different controller

    UINavigationController *new = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:new.viewControllers];
    [array insertObject:vc atIndex:0];
    [new setViewControllers:array];
}
```